# A confusion on type.__init__ in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.x, metaclass

Take a look at the following example

```
class Base(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dict_):
        print 'Base.__init__() with cls %s, name %s...' % (cls, name, )
        type.__init__(cls, name, bases, dict_)

M = Base('M', (object,), {})

class D1(Base):
    pass

class D2(M):
    pass
```

The output is

```
Base.__init__() with cls <class '__main__.M'>, name M...
Base.__init__() with cls <class '__main__.D2'>, name D2...
```

I feel so puzzled about the result,

1. Why `Base.__init__` be invoked for `D2`, even we have not creat an instance of `D2`?
2. Since `Base.__init__` be invoked for `D2`, why `D1` not?

Comment: Err... `Base(arguments)` invokes `Base.__init__`...

Comment: "Why `Base.__init__` be invoked for `D2`, even we have not creat an instance of `D2`?" - because you've created an instance of `Base`. That instance is `D2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Base.__init__` is called the first time when you do:

```
M = Base('M', (object,), {})
```

You're creating an instance of `Base`, so its `__init__` method gets called, nothing surprising.

It is called the second time when creating `D2` because creating a class calls the `__init__` method of the **metaclass** (yep, class of the class) which is `Base`; `D2` is an instance of `Base`.

It is not called for `D1` since `D1` is a subtype/subclass of `Base` and not an instance of it.

Notice what happens when you make `Base` the metaclass of `D1` instead of its superclass:

```
class D1(object):
    __metaclass__ = Base
    pass

# Base.__init__() with cls <class 'D1'>, name D1...
```

Comment: I am not familiar with how does `metaclass` work. So I still feel puzzled why `Base.__init__` is called when D2 is an instance of `Base`; even after reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python, because `__metaclass__` is not used here.

Comment: Another issue: does the position of `__metaclass__` matters?

Comment: [The basic principle of the __metaclass__](http://jfine-python-classes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/metaclass-attribute.html#the-basic-principle-of-the-metaclass)